# Against cold boot attacks: how to restrain sensitive information in Haskell

Tags: security, haskell

Is there any way to ensure key material gets securely erased from the memory after the program exits? Being able to erase it manually and keep the program running would be even better. As Haskell uses automated garbage collection (which may not happen at all if there is loads of free memory?), I assume that the second task is impossible. Could something that serves the purpose be implemented using FFI?

Comment: Yes, cold boot attacks are so common you have to worry about them. You can use ST, hold the data in STRef and scramble it after use. Dunno if you can mlock memory behind STRefs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GHC can return memory to the OS when it is no longer needed, so merely blanking the memory on exit won't achieve your goal. Garbage collection is a complicated business, but there is in general no way to ensure that old copies of your secure data are not returned to the OS memory pool.

However the OS will blank your memory before allocating it to another process.  If you don't trust the OS to keep your memory secure then you have a much bigger problem.

I'm not sure what you mean by "unreliable"; Haskell GC is reliable, but the program has comparatively little visibility of what is happening.

However if you are concerned merely with a cryptographic key rather than a big, complicated data structure then life gets a bit better. You can use a [Foreign Pointer](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.1/doc/html/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html) to point to a memory location for your key, and then make blanking that bit of memory into a part of your finaliser. You can even write a bit of code that allocates a block of memory, [mlocks](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) it, and then hands off foreign pointers to key-sized chunks of that memory on request, with finalisers that wipe the key. That would probably do what you want.

The point of a ForeignPtr is that it is guaranteed not to be moved or re-interpreted by the GC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I am not too familiar with all this "foreign" stuff, I'll wait and see whether an answer that points to existing code turns up and accept your answer if it doesn't. OS clearing the memory before handing it to other processes does not help here, because one cold just pull the plug and put the RAM modules to another machine. If it sounds like wanting to be too safe, think (laptop) disk encryption - it would be a good idea to flush unencrypted key material out of memory before suspending it. I also clarified my reluctance to rely on automatic GC in the original post.

Comment: There is nothing horrendously difficult about ForeignPtr.  See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/FFI for a tutorial.

Comment: @Andreas wouldn't pulling the plug empty the RAM of its data?

Comment: @amindfv For RAM data to stay intact, it is read and rewritten regularly. However, unpowering the RAM does not erase it, the data just fades out over time. Most RAM used today does not fade fast enough to prevent copying it, and even if it would at room temperature one could just freeze it first to make it last even longer. There is a paper on this issue at https://citp.princeton.edu/research/memory/

Comment: There are attacks which don't involve a power off. For instance you can plug in a bootable thumb drive and press reset; the thumb drive boots into a little program that dumps a memory image to a file. Some implementations of OHCI over firewire allow a connected device to send DMA commands that allow the whole of RAM to be imaged just by plugging in a device. So minimising the time key data is held in RAM is a Good Thing.

Comment: I'd call this broken design and say IO MMU is a Good Thing.